# VBScript to check if a image is loaded

Tags: vbscript

I'm very new to VBScript or any scripting for that matter.

I want the script to check whether an image is loaded. Below is the script up to the point of where I'm stuck.

```
strURL="https://www.Test.com/" 

strUser="******" 

strPass="******" 

Set oIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","IE_")  
Timeout=20 'seconds  
oIE.visible=1 : BeginTimer = Timer  
oIE.Navigate strURL  
i=0 : bElementsLoaded=false  
Set CODA_Element_1 = Nothing
Do While (oIE.ReadyState<>4 Or Not(bElementsLoaded)) And i < Timeout  
WScript.Sleep(1000):i=i+1  
On Error Resume Next 

  Set CODA_Element_1 = oIE.Document.getElementById("user")
  Set CODA_Element_2 = oIE.Document.getElementById("password")
  Set CODA_Element_3 = oIE.Document.getElementById("next")


   If     (Not(CODA_Element_1 is Nothing)) Then  

    bElementsLoaded=true  

   End If 

On Error Goto 0  

Loop 

CODA_Element_1.value=strUser 
CODA_Element_2.value=strPass 
CODA_Element_3.Click()
```

From here on in i have no idea.... The image i want to check is loaded is /codaprod/images/portal.jpg

In the below snippet of source code

```
<DIV id="esisplitpanelower" class="scroller" style="height:100%; overflow:auto">
<TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  height="100%" width="100%">
<TR><TD width="100%" height="100%"><TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0  height="100%" width="100%">
<TR><TD align="center" valign="top" width="100%" height="100%"><TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=3  align="center" valign="top" height="100%" width="100%">
<TR><TD align="center" width="100%" height="100%"><TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=3  align="center" height="100%" width="100%">
<TR><TD align="center"><IMG src="/codaprod/images/portal.jpg" title="Home Page">
</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
</TD>
</TR></TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Can somebody please show me how to check if this image is loaded? If loaded display `msgbox "Working!"` and if the image is not loaded then `msgbox "Not Working!"`

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `<img>`'s onload() method.

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
sub loadImage()
  msgbox "Image is loaded"
end sub
</script>

<img src="anyold.gif" onload="loadImage">
```

W3Schools gives a JavaScript version of that same thing: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_img_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can check using the image object's **complete** property
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp

Here's an example:

```
For Each pix In oIE.document.images
  Do Until pix.complete=true 
    WScript.Sleep 10
  Loop
Next
```

You need to tailor this to your precise image, possibly comparing the image object's **src** property for checking the precise image you want to know if it is loaded or not.